# What are the equivalent PC keyboard keys and mouse buttons of the Xbox 360 game controller buttons shown on the screen?

Tags: pc, dark-souls

The PC port of Dark Souls shows Xbox 360 game controller buttons on its in-game messages and the UI. However, I'm playing with a mouse and a keyboard. This makes learning the controls a bit awkward.

What are the equivalent (default) PC keyboard keys and mouse buttons of the Xbox 360 game controller buttons shown on the screen?

Comment: Not having the game myself I can't help directly, but a lot of these ports will usually have something in the options menu. Is there nothing there for Dark Souls?

Comment: @MatthewScharley it is, reputedly, a god-awful port.

Comment: @MatthewScharley There is none, AFAIK. You can configure the keys, but it doesn't say the Xbox 360 controller equivalent.

Comment: @galacticninja: You may be best looking in that list whenever you see a new control explanation popping up.

Comment: @MatthewScharley The control explanations only show the Xbox 360 controls, so looking at the key configuration settings is not very helpful. Hence, this question here in Gaming SE.

Comment: @galacticninja: oh goodness, kotekzot wasn't kidding then... good luck... :(

Comment: I've had a similar problem with NFS:TR. It took me a while to find out how to fix it. The problem was that I used a controller(don't remember which one anymore) and it was still registered on my computer. If you ever used and controller except for keyboard/mouse, try to delete them(and drivers or whatever they needed)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

| PC | Xbox 360 |
| --- | --- |
| <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd> | Forward, Back, Left, Right |
| <kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> | Camera controls (Second analogue stick) |
| <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd> | D-pad |
| <kbd>Page Up</kbd>, <kbd>Page Down</kbd> | RB, LB |
| <kbd>Insert</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> | X, Y |
| Menu / Stats pages, etc: <kbd>End</kbd> |  |
| <kbd>Q</kbd> | A |
| <kbd>E</kbd> | B |
| Lock on: <kbd>O</kbd> |  |
| Gesture menu: <kbd>G</kbd> |  |
| Controls your rolling, dashing, diving, etc: <kbd>Space</kbd> |  |
| Toggle 1H/2H Grip: <kbd>Alt</kbd> |  |
| Right Weapon Attack, Heavy: <kbd>U</kbd>, <kbd>LMB</kbd> |  |
| Right Weapon Attack, Light: <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>RMB</kbd> |  |
| Left Weapon Action / Block: <kbd>Shift</kbd> |  |
| Left Weapon Action / Parry: <kbd>Tab</kbd> |  |
| Confirm: <kbd>Enter</kbd> |  |
| Cancel: <kbd>Backspace</kbd> |  |

<sup>Note: If the Xbox 360 controller button is not listed above, it is not known what the equivalent button is. Please consider suggesting an edit to this answer, or commenting about it, if you know them.</sup>

---

Source(s): I've got Dark Souls. The keyboard controls are really not intuitive but all of the above are what you get. The in-game hints system is pretty much useless as it lists the keys for the 360 controller. For example, when telling you to do a critical attack it was listed as "when falling, press RB" - menus didn't say what that was but it's easy to work out when you start playing.

My advice is — get a controller. The game is very fun and playable with the keyboard and mouse but you will probably start to hate life, especially with the lock on if you're using a mouse since it is highly sensitive and just pressing one of the attack buttons can switch targets so your attack misses and you die.

Comment: Upvote for saying get a controller.  It's really horrid without.

Comment: Some of the PC keyboard keys still don't have Xbox 360 game controller equivalents written. Also, I am not sure if the 'second analog stick' is the left or right analog stick (I don't have a 360 controller). If anyone knows these, please suggest an edit or comment about it.

Comment: Steam actually explicitly suggests getting a controller...

Comment: and what is the equivalent of "rs" for the pc-keyboard?
thanks

Comment: In menus, neither *q* nor *e* work for the on-screen "A" or "B" keys – *Enter* and *Baskspace*, respectively, do.

Comment: By the way, is the game unplayable with just the keyboard and not the mouse? I find it pretty easy to work with the camera using just the keyboard, but I just started the game.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse really isn't all that useful when playing this game, it mostly just messes with your camera, unless you're a serious gamer and got one of those gaming mouses with all the fancy knobs and buttons.
I've been playing this for about 3 hours now, but being I've found some things that aren't on here (I like lists)

Ctrl+WASD allows you to walk instead of run

In the menu, Alt=Y; E=X; Space=B; Q=A; Backspace=Cancel; and switching between various menus and such is accomplished by use of the arrowkeys

galacticninja is correct in that there are a bunch contoller buttons that don't have key equivalents, but I'm pretty sure that there'll be updates that'll help